# Angular 5 case sensitivity

Tags: angular, rest, pojo

I have an Angular app which is served by a RESTful web service created using web-api2.

The api holds a class as below:

```
 public class PropertyDto {
  public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    public TransactionStatus ? TransactionStatus { get; set; }
    public bool ? IsNewHome { get; set; }
    ...other stuff....
}
```

I converted this class into a typescript class - and called it `Property` - for my angular app. I populate this class to post to the service and want to map response data to this class.

Everything works as expected when I build the object and send it to the server but my problem is that when I receive a response, the object that is mapped is all lowercase.

I build the object very simply as below:

```
var property = new Property();
property.Guid = "some-guid-value";
property.PropertyType = PropertyType.Default
....etc....
```

the posted json is below

```
{
   "Guid":"some-guid-value",
   "PropertyType":"0",
   ....etc....
}
```

I map the response as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class PropertyService {
  getProperty(id: string): Observable<Property> {
    this.property += this.agentId + "/" + id;
    return this.http.get<Property>(this.property);
  }
}

export class PropertyFormMapperComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._propertyService.getProperty(this._id).subscribe(property => {
      //here the properties of the property class are all lowercase
      //example below
    });
  }
}
```

example response

```
guid: "some-guid-value"
transactionStatus: 1
...etc...
```

What is the best way to manage this scenario.

**Things i've considered**

1. changing the class properties to lowercase
2. altering the service to return json objects with uppercase for the first letter
3. uppercase the first letter of each property the response when its returned to the client
4. having a class for request and response

**why I haven't done any of the above**

1. Cant work because it wouldn't map when I send to the server
2. I shouldn't be altering the service for a client limitation
3. Feels very hacky
4. I don't want a duplicate class and inconsistent casing

Finally I feel I should point, my knowledge in this area is limited so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: the problem here isn't in angular, the problem is that your server is built in an inconsistent manner where it expects upper camel case on the post but sends lower camel case on the get.  The server should expect and send consistent casing.  Since this is JSON the standard would be lower camel case. This isn't a "client limitation", its a server built in a frustrating manner that would make me pull my hair out.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I feel you make a fair point and I agree that it's very annoying. I guess I need to post a different question as the same class is used for the post request and get response

Comment: I'm gona go out on a limb and guess that whatever server framework you're using, if you just google this question, it's already answered

Comment: @bryan60 I realised I said I will ask another question, but I think you will be right, I'm just trying to find a solution now